# Add and assign to a new column in a dataframe through multiple "if" conditions within a single "loop"

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

I want to perform an iteration process on my data frame with multiple conditions (`if` statement). Each condition can add 1 to a new column (the target variable, **newVar**) if it is `true`, and zero if it is `false`. Finally, I can have my newVar column with an integer value corresponding to the number of true outputs in each condition cumulatively. For instance, a newVar with a value of 3 means that three times the conditions became true in total. It is like an add and assign operator += in Python. I can do this task with separate `if` statements and `loop`s, but I was wondering if I could just combine all in a tidy and coherent block of codes.

Below I provide my sample data frame and the lengthy way that I used to generate my newVar.

```
set.seed(1)
var1 <- sample(c(1:3, NA), 10, replace = TRUE)
var2 <- sample(c(1:3, NA), 10, replace = TRUE)
var3 <- sample(c(1:3, NA), 10, replace = TRUE)
var4 <- sample(c(1:3, NA), 10, replace = TRUE)
var5 <- sample(c(1:3, NA), 10, replace = TRUE)

df <- data.frame(var1, var2, var3, var4, var5)

# get rid of NA values by converting them to unwanted arbitrary number like 13
for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
  for (j in 1:ncol(df)){
    if (is.na(df[i,j])){
      df[i,j] <- 13
    }
  }
}

# condition 1: if either var1 and var2 has 1, add one to the new variable1
for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
  if ((df$var1[i] == 1)== TRUE | (df$var2[i] == 1) == TRUE) {
    df$newVar1[i] <- 1
  }
  else{
    df$newVar1[i] <- 0
  }
}

# condition 2: if either var3, var4 and var5 has 1, add one to the new variable2
for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
  if ((df$var3[i] == 1)== TRUE | (df$var4[i] == 1) == TRUE | (df$var5[i] == 1) == TRUE) {
    df$newVar2[i] <- 1
  }
  else{
    df$newVar2[i] <- 0
  }
}

# finally, summing them to make the newVar values
for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
  df$newVar[i] = df$newVar1[i] + df$newVar2[i]  
}
```

Comment: I want to mutate a new column (newVar) that add one to its value when ever a condition is true. It is like a score for each row based on defined conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you're looking for

```
df$score <- (rowSums(df[1:2] == 1, na.rm=TRUE) > 0) + (rowSums(df[3:5] == 1, na.rm=TRUE) > 0)
#    var1 var2 var3 var4 var5 score
#  1    1    3    1    2    2     2
#  2   NA    3    3    2    2     0
#  3    3    1    1    1    3     2
#  4    1    1    1   NA   NA     2
#  5    2    1    1    3   NA     2
#  6    1    2    1    1   NA     2
#  7    3    2    2   NA    2     0
#  8    3    2    1    3   NA     1
#  9    2    2    1    2    1     1
# 10    2    3    2    2    3     0
```

Be aware that R is a *vectorized* language, which means you can do things like `c(1, 2, 3, 4) + c(4, 3, 2, 1)` without tedious `for` loops.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(newVar = coalesce(
    if_any(var1:var2, ~.x == 1) + 
    if_any(var3:var5, ~.x == 1), 0))
```

Result

```
   var1 var2 var3 var4 var5 newVar
1     1    3    1    2    2      2
2    NA    3    3    2    2      0
3     3    1    1    1    3      2
4     1    1    1   NA   NA      2
5     2    1    1    3   NA      2
6     1    2    1    1   NA      2
7     3    2    2   NA    2      0
8     3    2    1    3   NA      1
9     2    2    1    2    1      1
10    2    3    2    2    3      0
```